# Create Android Alt Coin Wallet

Tags: wallet, altcoin, android

I am looking for base steps or general guidelines how to create lightweight  android wallet for existing alt coin "X".
So, lets start with simple questions:

1. Do I need to run a node on the server
2. Can I clone and configure existing open source android wallets. If yes - any help with this?

Would be happy to have any additional useful info as start point to create the wallet.

Answer (score 2):

Lightweight wallets use a simplified payment verification (SPV) mode which only requires them to download part of the blockchain so yes a full node is required,yes you can clone an existing opensource wallet but skills is required for that

Comment: so, 
a) basically I should run my own node to query it from android app?
b) what wallets example would be good to clone and configure to use as alt coin wallets?

Comment: i will use as example coinomi, coinomi is a multiple currency lightweight wallet if you check at source at from ine 130 - 217 you will see the supported currencies servers ip https://github.com/Coinomi/coinomi-android/blob/master/wallet/src/main/java/com/coinomi/wallet/Constants.java#L130 i suggest you to contact with coinomi in order to add your coin in their wallet else if you have skills play with the code